# Updating button state which is clicked, inside RenderItem of Flat-list, in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am new to React Native and trying to accomplish something like below, where simple list from server is rendering in a list with a button. Button, upon click, will be disabled and opacity will be changed.

I am able to create the UI but when I click any button that says Join, previous clicked button resets it state to original. In other words, only one button displays clicked state all the time.

[image]

so my code is something like

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {selectedIndices: false, groupsData: ''};
}
```

**Flatlist inside render method looks like**

```
<FlatList style={styles.list}
 data={this.state.groupsData}
 keyExtractor={(groups) => {
     return groups.groupId.toString();
 }}
 renderItem={(item, index) => {
     return this.renderGroupItem(item);
 }}/>
```

**RenderGroupItem**

```
renderGroupItem = ({item} )=>(
    <GroupItem group = {item} style={{height: '10%'}} onPress = {() => this.onJoinButtonPress(item)} 
    index = {this.state.selectedIndices}/>
)
```

**onJoinButtonPress**

```
onJoinButtonPress = (item) =>{
    this.setState({selectedIndices: true});
}
```

**GroupItem**

```
render(){
        if(this.props.group.groupId === this.props.index){
            return(
                <View style = {[styles.container]}>
                    <Image source={{uri: 'some Image Url'}} style={styles.roundImage}/>
                    <Text style={styles.groupText}>{this.props.group.name}</Text>
                    <View >
                        <TouchableOpacity style = {[styles.button, {opacity: 0.4}]} activeOpacity = { .5 } onPress = {this.props.onPress} 
                        disabled = {true}>
                            <Text style = {{color: 'white', fontSize: 12}}>Joined</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>                
                </View>
            );
        }else{
            return(
                <View style = {styles.container}>
                    <Image source={{uri: 'Some Image Url'}} style={styles.roundImage}/>
                    <Text style={styles.groupText}>{this.props.group.name}</Text>
                    <View >
                        <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.button} activeOpacity = { .5 } onPress = {this.props.onPress}>
                            <Text style = {{color: 'white', fontSize: 12}}>Join</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>                
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
```

Now I know that I need to pass an array or hasmap which contains mapping of items that have been clicked but I dont know how to do that. Need desperate help here.

Comment: You should update the groupsData with the id of pressed item instead of using the indices , why are you using a boolean for indices ?

Comment: My problem is eventually solved using this link
https://hackernoon.com/how-to-highlight-and-multi-select-items-in-a-flatlist-component-react-native-1ca416dec4bc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to overcome above problem after maintaining a boolean in the groupsData. Upon selection, I update a boolean "groupsJoined" in groupsData and update the state of groupsData which will invoke render. Inside GroupsItem class, I added a check that if data from props has joinedGroups as true then render selected state else non selected state.

Courtesy https://hackernoon.com/how-to-highlight-and-multi-select-items-in-a-flatlist-component-react-native-1ca416dec4bc